# Halmos' notation for unions

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Halmos defines a union of sets $X \in \mathcal{C}$, where $\mathcal{C}$ is a collection of sets, as
$$
U = \{x : x \in X \text{ for some $X \in \mathcal{C}$}\}.
$$
I have two questions on this definition which I'll get to, but he goes on to present the following notation for union:
$$
\bigcup \left\{ X : X \in \mathcal{C}\right\}.
$$
Here are my questions.

1. He specifies $U$ as the set of "$x$" and then specifies properties for those $X$, but without a clearly defined universe of discourse, this definition seems unclear. Does that universe need to be specified in advance for this definition to make sense, or is it ok to specify the universe thereafter, as we seem to do? He does the same in the second notation. I view the specification of a set as saying "the set of $x$ in this universe satisfying the properties after the colon." It's possible this is just taken for granted.
2. The second notation doesn't make sense to me. It seems that we're taking a union over singleton sets, each of which is of the form $\{X\}$. So if I have sets $A_1, \ldots, A_n$ and $\mathcal{C}$ is the collection of $A_i$, then the union is
   $$
   \{A_1\} \cup \{A_2\} \cup \ldots \cup \{A_n\},
   $$
   instead of what I perceive the union to be, which is
   $$
   A_1 \cup A_2 \cup \ldots \cup A_n. 
   $$

I'd appreciate if someone could help me understand these points.

Comment: Please, ask one question per post.

Answer (score 3):

The notation
$$
\bigcup \left\{ X : X \in \mathcal{C}\right\}.
$$
is indeed a bit misleading. It should be interpreted as the union of all members of the family $\left\{ X : X \in \mathcal{C}\right\}$, not as the union of the singletons $\{X\}$. Here, the $\bigcup$ symbol operates on a family and does not take an index set as a below argument. Really, this is a convention.
$$
\bigcup \left\{ X : X \in \mathcal{C}\right\} = \bigcup_{X \in \mathcal{C}} X.
$$

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful. Is it also a convention to take the universal set for granted? I'm still confused on this point.

Comment: This is a shorthand. The universe should be specified, e.g. $\{x \in X : x \hbox{ satisfies } P(x)\}$. But often it is omitted when there is no ambiguity. A bit like in analysis when we speak of the square function $x \mapsto x^2$ without specifying the domain of definition.

Comment: Ok so the universe is just understood? As in, there's some big set $U$ for which $X \subset U$ for every $X \in \mathcal{C}$? If so, this makes perfect sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1.the first notation $$ U={x:x∈X for some X∈C}.$$
can be read as " U is equal to x, such that x∈X for some X∈C"  so $x ∈X for some X∈C$ is the rule thats given to identify what kind of x would satisfy U, so i guess in this case x could be anythings, which U is anythings that follow the rules given.

2. the second notation ⋃{X:X∈C}.can be read as $⋃{X:X∈C}$.  where all i do is just $$ the nation

Comment: The first point is still confusing to me, because Halmos states that there is no "universal set," so I'm not sure exactly what "anything" means here.

Comment: there is no universal set can be justify as there is no set of all set by Russell’s-Paradox. where in this case the range is given after. I mean , its more nice if they put it this way :U={x∈X:forsomeX∈C.} but it works the same